# How to recover a deleted file in cloud-storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How to recover a deleted file in cloud-storage? A client backup file disappeared. Does google have any routine that may have come to delete some files?

Comment: I'm affraid that this question has nothing to do with Development / Programming, so this is voted a offtopic (Maybe take a look @ https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Google gives the developers full control of their data. As it stated in [Cloud Storage > Deleting Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects) documentation `"Warning: Object deletion cannot be undone."`.

To prevent this happening again in the future, you can protect your files with `Object Versioning`. Follow the [Cloud Storage > Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) documentation for more information.